# Julia: Base function 10,000x quicker then similar function

Tags: binary, julia

I'm playing around with the decimal to binary converter 'bin()' in Julia, wanting to improve performance. I need to use BigInts for this problem, and calling bin() with a bigInt from within my file outputs the correct binary representation; however, calling a function similar to the bin() function costs a minute in time, while bin() takes about .003 seconds. Why is there this huge difference?

```
function binBase(x::Unsigned, pad::Int, neg::Bool)
    i = neg + max(pad,sizeof(x)<<3-leading_zeros(x))
    a = Array(Uint8,i)
    while i > neg
        a[i] = '0'+(x&0x1)
        x >>= 1
        i -= 1
    end
    if neg; a[1]='-'; end
    ASCIIString(a)
end



function bin1(x::BigInt, pad::Int)
    y = bin(x)
end



function bin2(x::BigInt, pad::Int,a::Array{Uint8,1}, neg::Bool)
    while pad > neg
        a[pad] = '0'+(x&0x1)
        x >>= 1
        pad -= 1
    end
    if neg; a[1]='-'; end
    ASCIIString(a)
end




function test()
    a = Array(Uint8,1000001)
    x::BigInt= 2
    x = (x^1000000)


    @time bin1(x,1000001)
    @time bin2(x,1000001,a,true)

end

test()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted by Felipe Lema, Base delegates BigInt printing to GMP, which can print BigInts without doing any intermediate computations with them – doing lots of computations with BigInts to figure out their digits is quite slow and ends up allocating a lot of memory. The bottom line: doing `x >>= 1` is extremely efficient for things like Int64 values but not that efficient for things like BigInts.

Comment: How come BigInt is accepted by the Base.bin function, as that function requires an unsigned number? Is the BigInt I pass broken into chunks somewhere? Thank you Stefan, I really appreciate all of the hard work you put in to the language.

Comment: There are multiple definitions of `Base.bin`: the appropriate one is chosen by what is referred to as "type dispatch". In this case, it calls `Base.base`, which in turn calls the GMP function: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/2c1ac1814f2b41824f69d827ccc6fc20ea4904aa/base/gmp.jl#L496-L506

Answer (score 4):

Using [julia's profiling tools](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/profile/) I can see that Base.bin is calling a C function from [libGMP](https://gmplib.org/), which has all sorts of machine specific optimizations (somewhere [here](https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp-5.1/file/7bd00c4f3d66/mpn) is `mpn_get_str` that [is being called](https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp-5.1/file/7bd00c4f3d66/mpz/get_str.c#l89)).

```
@profile bin1(x,1000001)
Profile.print()
Profile.clear()
@profile bin2(x,1000001,a,true)
Profile.print()
Profile.clear()
```

I could also see a huge difference in bytes allocates (bin1:1000106, bin2:62648125016) which would require some more profiling and tunning, but I guess the previous paragraph is enough for an answer.